# How to read all apps notification in my app when my app is closed?

Tags: android-activity, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

```
    package com.example.notificationlistener;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
    {
        Log.i("From service","onNotificationPosted");

        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();

//      if("com.twitter.android".equalsIgnoreCase(pack))
//      if("com.google.android.gm".equalsIgnoreCase(pack))
        {
            String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();

            Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;

            String title = extras.getString("android.title");
            String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();

            Log.i("Package",pack);
            Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
            Log.i("Title",title);
            Log.i("Text",text);

            Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
            msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
            msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
            msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
            msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn)
    {
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");
    }

}

this is my service class 

    package com.example.notificationlistener;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

     TableLayout tableLayout;
     TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
     String text = "noText";
     String title = "noTitle";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, null);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("Msg"));

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.w("From MainActivity", "broadcast receiver is called");

            String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String ticker = intent.getStringExtra("ticker");
            title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            text = intent.getStringExtra("text");

            Log.d("mainActivity_pack", pack);
            Log.d("mainActivity_title", title);
            Log.d("mainActivity_text", text);
            Log.d("mainActivity_ticker", ticker);
//            Log.d("mainActivity", sender);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "New Message", System.currentTimeMillis()+5000);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, text, null);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            notificationManager.notify(2, notification);

            speak();

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TextView textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
            textview.setTextSize(20);
            textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B0719"));
            textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(pack +"<br><b>" + title + " : </b>" + text));
            tr.addView(textview);
            tableLayout.addView(tr);

        }
    };

    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (textToSpeech != null)
        {
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();
        }

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(onNotice);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else
            {

                speak();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

     private void speak()
     {
          textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
      }`enter code here`

}
```

this is my activity. i am trying to read notification and resend them through my app so done this and i am able to get the notifications but when my app is closed its not working so please suggest me some changes or suggestions...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put your broadcast receiver into a service. Activities don't run when the app is closed. Services do. Start your services from your activity. Then they will continue to run even after closing the app.